# Error de sintaxis en insertar datos a base de datos PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, formularios

Quiero insertar datos en  mi base de datos pero suelta este error:

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Aqui esta el codigo del guardar.php , que es donde guardo mis datos de mi formulario
Apreciaria mucho la ayuda !.

```
include ("../includes/conexion.php");

$proveedor = $_POST["proveedor"];
$forma_pago = $_POST["forma_pago"];
$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
$codigo= $_POST["codigo"];
$nombre= $_POST["nombre"];
$unidad_medida=  $_POST["unidad_medida"]; 
$unidades_disponibles = $_POST["cantidad"];
$fecha_vencimiento= $_POST["fecha_vencimiento"];
$precio_unitario = $_POST["precio_unitario"]; 

$guardar_compra = "INSERT INTO tblfacturacompra(proveedor,forma_pago,fecha) 
VALUES ('$proveedor','$forma_pago','$fecha')";
//echo $guardar_compra;
$guardar_materia_prima = "INSERT INTO tblmateriaprima(codigo,nombre,unidad_medida,unidades_disponibles,fecha_vencimiento) 
VALUES ('$codigo','$nombre','$unidad_medida','$unidades_disponibles','$fecha_vencimiento')";
//echo $guardar_materia_prima;exit;
if ($conexion->query( $guardar_compra  &&   $guardar_materia_prima) === TRUE) {
   /*
   echo'<script type="text/javascript"> 
   alert("Factura Creada!");
   window.location.href="registro_compra.php";   
   </script>';
*/
echo "si";
}else {
   /*echo'<script type="text/javascript"> 
   alert("Algo falló! Volver a intentar.");
   window.location.href="registro_compra.php";   
   </script>';"*/
   echo "Error: {$conexion->error}";   
}

include ("../includes/desconexion.php");
?>
```

Comment: Puede que en el apartado de values estés usando comillas en algún campo de tipo numérico

Comment: Tu problema está en el `if ($conexion->query( ... ) )` porque en el mejor de los casos, el manejador interpretará que quieres ejecutar dos consultas al mismo tiempo con `query()`, lo cual no es posible. Para hacer eso tendrías que usar multiquery. Es mejor ejecutar ambas consultas por separado, guardando una variable por cada una y luego sí puedes verificar ambas variables juntas en un `if` si fuera necesario.

Comment: O, puedes evaluar así: **`if ( ($conexion->query($guardar_compra) && ($conexion->query($guardar_materia_prima) ) {  //código } else { // código }`** ahí cada consulta se ejecuta por separado. El === TRUE es redundante, por eso lo he omitido.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está aquí:

```
if ($conexion->query( $guardar_compra  &&   $guardar_materia_prima) === TRUE) {
```

Le estás pidiendo a `query()` que ejecute esto:

```
$guardar_compra  &&   $guardar_materia_prima
```

Pero el resultado de eso es `1` simplemente. Hagamos una prueba simple:

```
$guardar_compra="INSERT 1";
$guardar_materia_prima="INSERT 2";

$loQueEstasEnviando=$guardar_compra  &&   $guardar_materia_prima;
echo $loQueEstasEnviando;
```

**Salida:**

```
1
```

Como podrás comprender, no le estás enviando una consulta válida a `query()` en ningún caso.

Podrías solventar el problema enviando cada consulta por separado, algo así:

```
if ( $conexion->query($guardar_compra) && $conexion->query($guardar_materia_prima) ) {
    echo "si";
}else {
   echo "Error: {$conexion->error}";   
}
```

Ahí se ejecuta cada consulta por separado que es lo correcto. Si por si acaso está en tu espíritu pensar que se pueden pasar dos consultas juntas, señalo que, en el caso de `mysqli` tendrías que hacerlo con [`multi_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php), escribiendo las consultas separadas por punto y coma. En el caso de PDO, me parece, que necesitarás emular las consultas preparadas y recurrir a algunas prácticas truculentas y quizá peligrosas, por lo que no sería recomendable hacerlo. Tampoco parece que sea la mejor idea tratar de usar o de habilitar multi query.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias !!! ya lo pude solucionar, entendi clara la explicación, pero tengo una duda,  esas dos tablas en la  base de datos(en el codigo son las variables), tienen una tabla intermedia, una tabla compuesta, el registro se guarda solamente en las tablas individuales,, como hago para que se guarde en la tabla compuesta? debo generar otra variable de inserción, yo pensé que se llenaban automaticamente pero veo que no.

Comment: @KAROLYULIETHPACHECORODRIGUE me alegro de que te haya servido. Para la inserción automática tendrías que programar un disparador (TRIGGER) que se ejecute cada vez que ocurra un INSERT en la tabla principal. Este tipo de eventos se programan en la base de datos, no en PHP. Revisa el Manual de Referencia al respecto muy si hay alguna duda puedes abrir otra pregunta. Si alguna de las respuestas dadas aquí resuelve este aspecto del problema puedes marcarla como solución.

Comment: Gracias!, y si quiero hacerlo e codigo php , como podria ? es decir que no sea automatica la inserción , yo quiero que en esa tabla compuesta se guarden los datos al igual que en las otras tablas con el codigo de arriba.

Comment: @KAROLYULIETHPACHECORODRIGUE si quieres hacerlo desde PHP tienes que escribir tu consulta `INSERT` como haces con las otras y ejecutarla con `query()`. En MySQL hay una función llamada `lastinsert_id` para recuperar el ID autoincremental de una fila que se acaba de insertar, por si lo necesitas para  la inserción en la tabla secundaria, pero si tienes conexiones concurrentes debes verificar cómo funciona.

Answer (score -1):

Puede que tu error este en los select, ya que no estas concatenando correctamente las variables.

ejemplo tu tienes esta linea de la siguiente manera...

```
$guardar_compra = "INSERT INTO tblfacturacompra(proveedor,forma_pago,fecha) 
VALUES ('$proveedor','$forma_pago','$fecha')";
```

y en este caso podrias concatenarlas de la siguiente manera...

```
$guardar_compra = "INSERT INTO tblfacturacompra(proveedor,forma_pago,fecha) 
VALUES ('".$proveedor."','".$forma_pago."','".$fecha."')";
```

y tu código completo quedaría de esta manera...

```
include ("../includes/conexion.php");

$proveedor = $_POST["proveedor"];
$forma_pago = $_POST["forma_pago"];
$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
$codigo= $_POST["codigo"];
$nombre= $_POST["nombre"];
$unidad_medida=  $_POST["unidad_medida"]; 
$unidades_disponibles = $_POST["cantidad"];
$fecha_vencimiento= $_POST["fecha_vencimiento"];
$precio_unitario = $_POST["precio_unitario"]; 

$guardar_compra = "INSERT INTO tblfacturacompra(proveedor,forma_pago,fecha) 
VALUES ('".$proveedor."','".$forma_pago."','".$fecha."')";
//echo $guardar_compra;
$guardar_materia_prima = "INSERT INTO tblmateriaprima(codigo,nombre,unidad_medida,unidades_disponibles,fecha_vencimiento) 
VALUES ('".$codigo."','".$nombre."','".$unidad_medida."','".$unidades_disponibles."','".$fecha_vencimiento."')";
//echo $guardar_materia_prima;exit;
if ($conexion->query( $guardar_compra  &&   $guardar_materia_prima) === TRUE) {
   /*
   echo'<script type="text/javascript"> 
   alert("Factura Creada!");
   window.location.href="registro_compra.php";   
   </script>';
*/
echo "si";
}else {
   /*echo'<script type="text/javascript"> 
   alert("Algo falló! Volver a intentar.");
   window.location.href="registro_compra.php";   
   </script>';"*/
   echo "Error: {$conexion->error}";   
}

include ("../includes/desconexion.php");
?>
```

Comment: La primera forma es correcta, puedes usar variables y comillas simples dentro de una cadena entre comillas dobles, de hecho es mejor hacerlo así, es mucho más claro.